# How to connect to REST API as datasource in AWS QuickSight for creating Reports?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, datasource, amazon-quicksight

Just wanted to know how to connect to REST API as datasource in AWS QuickSight for creating Reports and Dashboards? If not in case of any alternative approach or related links to that would be more helpful! Thanks in Advance!  -  Vicky!

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no direct support to extract data from Rest APIs from Quicksight, only online databases, however there are third parties that for a price can help you bridge the gap

**Skyvia** allows you to connect a google sheet (which can make API calls to extract the data) to quicksight

https://skyvia.com/data-integration/analyze-google-sheets-with-quicksight

**DataDDO** offers a bridging service between an API and several services. This is the cheapest of the 3 services
https://www.dataddo.com/?hsLang=en

**CData** has a product that pulls data from a REST API and exposes it as a database source
https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/rest-connect-quicksight.rst

Same as **Zappysys**
https://zappysys.com/products/ssis-powerpack/ssis-web-api-integration-pack/

On the other hand the other option would be to create a program that consumes the API regularly and saves it into a database so you can consume it from quicksight, this might be the most inexpensive option but slower in times of readiness.

Take a look at this project which might shorten the development time by providing an interface for querying APIs as if it were a SQL query
https://github.com/betodealmeida/shillelagh

Answer (score 1):

As of the today, Quicksight **doesn't** directly support REST API as a datasource.

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/supported-data-sources.html#service-data-sources

An alternative is you extract it using Python or your preferred tool and dump it in Amazon S3.